# How to change the primary category of the iPhone app after submission?

Tags: iphone

I accidentally submitted my app in the wrong primary category. The app is now submitted to the app store. How can I change the primary category?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With an update.

Comment: ..as seen here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/11_EditingandUpdatingAppInformation/EditingandUpdatingAppInformation.html

Answer (score 4):

Categories and keywords are the 2 things you can't change once you submit your app for approval. You can change these in subsequent updates.

Sometime the Apple reviewers will correct categories that are not relevant to the app.

You can also reject the binary, change the category and submit again.