# How to change the category of an iOS App in the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the primary category of the iPhone app after submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059796/how-to-change-the-primary-category-of-the-iphone-app-after-submission)

How do I go about doing this now that Apple has made it a pain in the neck? Is it still possible to do it with an update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a programming question, but I can confirm that yes, the Category is editable when submitting a new version of your app.  So you can change it with an update.